# CTAS vs reclaim tablespace

Tags: database, optimization, query-optimization

I have a table with 10+ million data. My table Insert/update/delete are frequently performed. I want to reclaim unused space to optimize my access to table. What is best way to achieve this on production environment?

I am thinking to perform CTAS and add all constraints to my table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, then I would agree that a CTAS would be the best.